# Are there best practices for deduplicating records when using auto-ingest Snowpipes?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Currently in Snowflake we have configured an auto-ingest Snowpipe connected to an external S3 stage as documented [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-s3.html#option-2-configuring-amazon-sns-to-automate-snowpipe-using-sqs-notifications). This works well and we're copying records from the pipe into a "landing" table. The end goal is to MERGE these records into a final table to deal with any duplicates, which also works well. **My question is around how best to safely perform this MERGE without missing any records?** At the moment, we are performing a single data extraction job per-day so there is normally a point where the Snowpipe queue is empty which we use as an indicator that it is safe to proceed, however we are looking to move to more frequent extractions where it will become harder and harder to guarantee there will be no new records ingested at any given point.

Things we've considered:

1. Temporarily pause the pipe, MERGE the records, TRUNCATE the landing table, then unpause the pipe. I believe this should technically work but it is not clear to me that this is an advised way to work with Snowpipes. I'm not sure how resilient they are to being paused/unpaused, how long it tends to take to pause/unpause, etc. I am aware that paused pipes can become "stale" after 14 days ([link](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-manage.html#resuming-a-stale-pipe)) however we're talking about pausing it for a few minutes, not multiple days.
2. Utilize transactions in some way. I have a general understanding of SQL transactions, but I'm having a hard time determining exactly if/how they could be used in this situation to guarantee no data loss. The general thought is if the MERGE and DELETE could be contained in a transaction it may provide a safe way to process the incoming data throughout the day but I'm not sure if that's true.
3. Add in a third "processing" table and a task to [swap](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table.html#parameters) the landing table with the processing table. The task to swap the tables could run on a schedule (e.g. every hour), and I believe the key is to have the conditional statement check both that there are records in the landing table AND that the processing table is empty. As this point the MERGE and TRUNCATE would work off the processing table and the landing table would continue to receive the incoming records.

Any additional insights into these options or completely different suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: For option #3 the ALLOW_OVERLAPPING_EXECUTION = FALSE (default) [parameter](https://snowflakecommunity.force.com/s/article/Overlapping-Tree-of-Task-Runs-Prevented-by-Default-Pending) on the root swap task should help guarantee it is safe to proceed however it still might make sense to check if the processing table is empty in case a previous task tree failed for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into table streams which record insertions/updates/deletions to your snowpipe table. You can then merge off the stream to your target table which then resets the offset. Use a task to run your merge statement. Also, given it is snowpipe, when creating your stream it is probably best to use an append only stream

However, I had a question here where in some circumstances, we were missing some rows. Our task was set to 1min intervals, which may be partly the reason. However I never did get to the end of it, even with Snowflake support.

What we did notice though was that using a stored procedure, with a transaction and also running a select on the stream before the merge, seems to have solved the issue i.e. no more missing rows

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DeanFlinter! I think streams could be a great way to go. My initial uncertainty around truncating the landing table seems to be a non-issue based on the [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams.html#types-of-streams) and some testing.